# How to automate the \label-ing of equations?

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, numbering, kile

I'm not sure if the way `LaTex` works allows for automatically labeling of, for example, `align` environments. This would require that the environment has an internal counter. However, when placing an environment between two previously placed ones, the algorithm would give the last environment a different label that the one assigned in a previous compilation, which is not what we want.

However, would it be possible to build an external solution? One idea is based on the editor. Perhaps it is possible to assign that a shortcut inserts not only the code for the environment but also a code for the label which outputs a successive number every time one uses the shortcut.

I'm specially interested in a solution for this using `Kile` which is my main editor.

Comment: I don't get it. If I put in the code `\begin{align}\label{eq:x} x&=x \\ \label{eq:f} f(x)&=f(x) \end{align}` then I can refer to them by `\eqref{eq:x}` and `\eqref{eq:f}`. What other solution you want?

Comment: You need to distinguish between _labels_ (assigned by the author in `\label{<label name>}`) and the actual equation _number_ (assigned internally be several counters) that can be referred to by `\eqref{<label name>}` and similar `ref` commands.

Comment: @tohecz yes, I want a way to automate the labeling process so that I don't have to write \label{eq:f} on every equation.

Comment: It is quite possible if you NEVER delete the aux file, or NEVER delete some file that is used to track this information. But I think that it is not good practice in any way. It will quickly be left with wrong numbers as one will occasionally delete such a file, intently or not.

Comment: @zeroth I don't care about that inconvenience, I just want a quick and dirty solution for avoid labeling every equation by hand

Comment: @Barefeg You do not need to label any equation unless you reference it, LaTeX will automatically number the equations and deal with inserted equations automatically. The label is an internal reference for _you_ to manage cross references, it makes no sense to generate the labels automatically.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know that I 'do not need to label an equation unless I make reference to it' but for me it's more efficient to label all of then so that if in any moment I need to reference an equation (I'm talking an ongoing project written in latex, not only typesetting notes from paper or similar) then it's as easy as looking at its label with showlabels package and writing it down. Instead, if I do like you say, then I have to go hunt that equation in some remote place in the code. In that case it makes sense to do it beforehand and automatically.

Comment: as the posted answer shows, emacs (of course:-) can do this, but I still think it's just wrong:-) Never used Kile so I can't actually help if you do want this, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Kile solution, but an [`emacs`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) one.

That editor and its [`AUCTeX-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) provide out-of-the-box automatic labelling of every labellable environment or command.

For example, when you type `C-c C-s` to insert a structure heading, after prompting you for the level of the heading and its title, it will insert the heading command into the document, together with a label based on these two information.

In the same way, typing `C-c C-e` to insert an environment and selecting the `equation` environment (or `align`, etc.) will insert the environment, together with a label of the form `eq:nn` where `nn` is the number of already generated labels +1.

Furthermode, if you combine it with the excellent [`reftex-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html), you can use its features to retrieve easily the label of an equation or a heading based on the context of this label (for example, the content of the equation environment or the title of the sectioning command associated with the label).

All these features, with suitable settings, [will also work as you would expect in a multi-file document](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Multifile).

Comment: You do use "anonymous" labels? I've _hoped_ that it's something people don't do... :(

Comment: Section labels are definitely not anonymous. I also usually set relevant names for "important" equations. But sometimes there isn't really any name that would describe the equation well-enough (for example one in many intermediate results in a long calculation). And the ability to view context through the label replaces quite efficiently the need for an explicit name, in my opinion.

Comment: Also, as the OP stated in a comment to his question, anonymous labels make sense in a workflow using `showlabels` from `mathtools`. This way, every equation has a label you can use later if needed. And then it will be time, if you want, to choose a more relevant label (it's a matter of a simple search-and-replace). But I still find it way better than blind-backtracking to the position of the equation, add the label, and then go back to where you were working.